# iptables - netfilter bug

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

In Ubuntu docs I saw this sample script which is mentioning netfilter bug:

```
# Workaround bug in netfilter
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack -p icmp --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
```

I wonder which bug it's referring and more details on how it will behave without this line

Answer (score 0):

The following link gives some details:
http://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter-devel/2006-July/025098.html

It seems to be related to errors made by p2p traffic.

Comment: Not so clear what was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

what's the date of the doc ? propably it's something obsolete

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router/Firewall 2009-12-19. Would be glad if someone confirm that it's fixed and I don't need this workaround.